# Prototypal inheritance chain with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
Person.prototype.talk = function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
//creating a Person object for extension
var manager = new Person('jon', 'doe');
console.log(manager.talk());
//Manager prototype..but doesn't inherit Person methods 
function Manager(firstName, lastName, accessCode) {
    //shared properties
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;

    this.accesscode = accessCode;
}
function personChecker(person) {
    var returnCode = 0;
    if (person instanceof Person) {
        returnCode = 1;
    }
    else if (person instanceof Manager) {
        returnCode = 2;
    }
    return returnCode;
}
console.log(personChecker(manager));
```

Is it possible to share a prototype and have a different constructor?  I would like to have Manager inherit everything from Person (and then extend it) and have a function switch on the prototype and do something different depending on the argument passed to the `personChecker` function

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however `instanceof` might not work as expected then. What do you actually want to do? That "function switch" sounds like a bad idea. Are you sure you don't want to "subclass" Person?

Comment: @Bergi I want some sort of functionality where I have a method that can take a manager, janitor and president object which inherit from Person.  How should I differentiate between those types?  Should I use something like `hasOwnProperty` instead of switching on the prototype?

Comment: Inheriting three times from Person sounds like the right thing - but then they don't have the same prototype ("share"). Whether it's better to distinguish the instances by calling their own methods or by instanceof-checking them should be another question.

Comment: @Bergi so let's say that the personChecker function  appends the firstName and lastName properties on the page, but it does so in a different color depending on the person, manager, etc.  How would that be implemented?  Would I switch on to be able to tell the difference?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: You could always add an extra field to your objects to tell what class they belong to. So you would do `this.personType = "JANITOR"`, `this.personType = "MANAGER"`, etc.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Why don't you give each person a method that lets them choose their own color?

Comment: @Bergi because it seems to me the color information doesn't belong to the person, but the page.  So I thought it might be a better idea to keep a method somewhere else.

Comment: @missingno I have done that before when deserializing .NET interface types, and it's a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, inheritance is generally done like this:

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

`Object.create` creates a new object with the object passed as the first argument in its prototype chain.

If you need to support old browsers that don't have `Object.create`, you can do the "prototype dance" instead:

```
function F(){}
F.prototype = Person.prototype;
Manager.prototype = new F();
```

In any case, avoid code calling the constructor to get such an object (`Manager.prototype = new Person()`), this is a well-known antipattern and will break as soon as your constructor relies on any of its arguments (and it causes other, more subtle problems).

Comment: Interesting, I think this is what I really wanted to do.  What are some of the more subtle problems this antipattern causes?

Comment: I think the most common problem is that anything the constructor does with `this` will happen to your new prototype object, when the assumption is probably that `this` is just an instance object.

Comment: Thank you, This is the best explanation I've come across yet!

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to support this inheritance:

```
// create a blank function to pass the prototype
var blank = function() {};

// assign the prototype to inherit to the blank constructor
blank.prototype = Person.prototype;

// pass an instance of the prototype as the Manager prototype
Manager.prototype = new blank();

var person = new Person('John', 'Doe');
var manager = new Manager('Greg', 'Smith', 'access1234');

manager.talk(); // Greg Smith
person.talk(); // John Doe
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XF28r/

Note a Manager is also a Person so you need to switch the check around.

```
function personChecker(person) {
    var returnCode = 0;
    if (person instanceof Manager) {
        returnCode = 2;
    } else if (person instanceof Person) {
        returnCode = 1;
    }
    return returnCode;
}
```

Although note I would put this in a helper method:

```
function extend(parent, child) {

  var blank = function() {};
  blank.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new blank();
}
```

So then you can simply use it:

```
extend(Person, Manager);
```

As Bergi has mentioned in the comments, this can also be reduced down to:

```
function extend(parent, child) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
}
```

(works IE 9 upward)

Comment: Instead of that helper function, you should just use `Object.create` or a shim of it (@DaggNabbit: it's OK here, because he uses `blank` explicitly, although some explanation would've helped)

Comment: That's nice @Bergi, I didn't know that. IE9 upward but still. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
Person.prototype.talk = function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

function Manager(firstName, lastName, accessCode) {
    //shared properties
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;

    this.accesscode = accessCode;
}
Manager.prototype = new Person('jon', 'doe');

function personChecker(person) {
    var returnCode = 0;
    if (person instanceof Manager) {
        returnCode = 2;
    }
    else if (person instanceof Person) {
        returnCode = 1;
    }
    return returnCode;
}
```

Note that I have changed the order of the conditionals, because an instance of `Manager` is an instance of `Person` too:

```
var per = new Person('A', 'B');
per.talk();              // 'A B'
per instanceof Person;   // true
per instanceof Manager;  // false
personChecker(per);      // 1

var man = new Manager('A', 'B');
man.talk();              // 'A B'
man instanceof Person;   // true !!!!
man instanceof Manager;  // true !!!!
personChecker(man);      // 2
```

---

If you want to do it the good way, instead of

```
Manager.prototype = new Person('jon', 'doe');
```

use

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {constructor: {value: Manager}});
```

but it doesn't work on old browsers.

Comment: -1 Why are all your managers called jon doe? [Don't use `new` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi I thought that wootscootinboogie wanted "jon doe" to be a default name